# Can a player raise in the following scenario?

Tags: rules

Sorry if i'm not using the proper poker jargon, but i am not a poker expert in any way.

I need your help to figure out what the player Daniel can do in the following scenario:

No Limits Texas Holdem Poker.
Four players game.
Post flop.
Small blind amount is 5.

Players are Ana, Boris (dealer button), Chris, Daniel.

C. open the betting phase.

C bets 20.
D calls.
A bets 30, and goes all-in. This is not a full raise.
B calls.

C cannot raise. C calls by betting 10.

In this situation can Daniel raise?
In case he can raise what is the minumum amount he has to bet in order his raise to be valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TDA Rule 44: Re-Opening the Bet](http://www.pokertda.com/custom_posts/view-official-tda-rules/)**

> In no-limit and pot limit, an all-in wager of less than a full raise does not reopen betting for a player who
>   has already acted and is not facing at least a full raise when the action returns to him. In limit, at least
>   50% of a full raise is required to re-open betting for players who have already acted. See Addendum.

According to the Poker TDA (Tournament Directors Association) rules, Daniel would not be able to reraise if a full raise was not placed.

Answer (score 2):

Chis SB
Daniel BB
Ana CO
Boris BTN

Ana should be opening pre flop
And Chris should be opening post flop

C 20
D 20
A 30 all in (not a min raise)
B 30

C 10 + 20
D

Yes D must call or fold
D has not technically been raised
Clearly D should call with those pot odds

B could have raised
I think the min raise would be 30 + 20 = 50 but not sure about that

Comment: http://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/